# Migrate HystrixCommands to Resilience4j

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, hystrix, resilience4j

Given Hystrix going into mainentance mode, I've been working on migrating a (rather large) codebase to Resilience4j.

I make heavy use of the following pattern with Hystrix:

```java
new HystrixCommand<SomeReturnValue>(DependencyKeys.DEPENDENCY) {
    @Override
    protected SomeReturnValue run() {
        return someExpensiveCall();
    }
}
    .observe()
```

And I want to replicate some of Hystrix' functionality with Resilience4j.

So far I have the following syntax to wire up an external call:

```java
resilience.single(DependencyKeys.DEPENDENCY, this::someExpensiveCall);
```

Where the `Resilience` class provides the `single` method:

```java
public <T> Single<T> single(ResilienceKey key, Callable<T> callable) {
    return Completable.complete()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(configuration.scheduler(key))
            .andThen(Single.defer(() -> Single.fromCallable(callable)
                    .lift(CircuitBreakerOperator.of(configuration.circuitBreaker(key)))
                    .lift(RateLimiterOperator.of(configuration.rateLimiter(key)))
                    .lift(BulkheadOperator.of(configuration.bulkhead(key)))
            ))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation());
}
```

How could this look to better resemble what you get with Hystrix in terms of circuit breaking and running the code on different thread pools, but in a more sane way. I really don't like starting the chain off with a `Completable.complete()` just so I can force the `observeOn` before the actual callable is wrapped.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no direct replacement of `HystrixCommand` in `Resilience4j`.
The most similar thing would be `CircuitBreaker.decorateCompletionStage` or `CircuitBreaker.executeCompletionStage`. Using this methods you can decorate any type on `CompletableFuture` supplier.
Other option would be to rely on our integration with different async modules like `rxjava2` or `reactor`.
And of course if none of this options doesn't fit you, please don't forget that `Resilience4j` is very unopinionated, modular and composable library. You can fit our circuit breaker in any kind of library on concurrency paradigm by using our 3 lowest level methods:

1. `CircuitBreaker.isCallPermitted`
2. `CircuitBreaker.onError`
3. `CircuitBreaker.onSuccess`

Same things are true for our other core components.
I hope this answer help at least a little bit. If you have any other questions, I'll be happy to help. Happy hacking

Comment: I appreciate the response! I'm using the rxjava2 integration, the `.lift(CircuitBreakerOperator.of(configuration.circuitBreaker(key)))` operators are effectively wrapping the deferred async function.
I guess the question I'm really asking is: assuming this works, is it best practice from an RxJava2 and Resilience4j point of view.